# Python Value Split/String

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have csv file which looks like this, and I need to sum the "total" base in "col a" value

| total | col a |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | ca_1,ca_2 |
| 200 | ca_3,ca_2_1 |
| 300 | ca_4,ca_2_1 |
| 400 | ca_2,ca_2_1 |
| 500 | ca_2,ca_2_1 |

expected output:

| total | col |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | ca_1 |
| 1000 | ca_2 |
| 200 | ca_3 |
| 1400 | ca_2_1 |
| 200 | ca_4 |

I am not sure how to do it using python.

Comment: Please be a bit more clear what you are doing. Where does the 1000 come from in your expected output?

Comment: ca_2 has 100,400 and 500 in total column

Answer (score 1):

[`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html):

```
col = 'col a'

out = (df.assign(**{col: df[col].str.split(',')})
         .explode(col)
         .groupby(col, as_index=False, sort=False).sum()
         [df.columns] # optional
      )
```

Output:

```
   total   col a
0    100    ca_1
1   1000    ca_2
2    200    ca_3
3   1400  ca_2_1
4    300    ca_4
```